# Simple Native Game - Android

Tags: android, mobile, accelerometer

For my mobile programming course we've finally been given some free reign to design and develop our own application. Our only requirement is that we have to implement geo-location or sensors in some way. I've chosen to try and make a very simple game which implements the accelerometer. The basic idea is that shapes will fall out of the sky (top of the screen) and you have to tilt the phone to make the 'guy' move and catch the shapes before they hit the ground. I have some ideas for game flavor but my teacher recommends I forsake that and just get the basic game play down (we only have 10 days).

So my question for you- does anyone have any high level advice for this application I'm going to tackle? Are there any good game/physics libraries for native android?

Comment: What do you mean answer them? I 'check' people who I believe answered my questions correctly. I need to answer my own questions?

Comment: If you found the answer for yourself, you can answer your own questions. BTW, I mean you have to mark the answers as accepted if they helped you solve your problem. This way you can help people with the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By native I'm assuming you mean the SDK, and not the NDK since you haven't added the `android-ndk` tag.

The two game engines best suited for your needs are [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) and [Libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). They both have the Box2D physics engine as well. AndEngine comes with several examples, and combining a few of them could give you what you need. Both engines have a good community support as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

http://www.andengine.org/

Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Hei Friend,
[Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) is what I recommend for this

Thank You